# The Less parent selector error with variable

Tags: less

I have the class

```
.el-button{&_radius(@color){...}}
```

to use in other classes for example:

```
.block{.el-button_radius(@green)}
```

but parser retrieve error: "Missing closing ')'"
if i use it without parent selector - &

```
.el-button_radius(@color){...}
```

it is good

is it possible?

Comment: how can i use it with "&"

Comment: You can't create parametric mixins like this (it just does not make any sense) - use [namespaces](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-namespaces-and-accessors) instead. [For example](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%5Cn%2F%2F%20usage%3A%5Cndiv%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.el-button.radius(42)%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%2F%2F%20impl.%5Cn.el-button%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.radius(%40value)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bla-bla%3A%20%40value%3B%20%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%20%20%22%7D).